# Eclipse: Installing Karma and Jasmine in Angular project

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, jasmine, karma-runner, nodeclipse

Is it possible to take advantage of the Nodeclipse addon in order to add Karma and Jasmine to an AngularJS project in Eclipse?  I want to download the Karma and Jasmine modules inside of Eclipse, or at least I want to take advantage of the installed node.exe to download the modules to my project directory.

Comment: How would you do that without IDE?

Comment: @PaulVerest Are you asking how would you add Karma and Jasmine to an AngularJS project outside of an IDE?

Comment: I know nothing about Karma and Jasmine. How would you or anyone install it? start a feature request on https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/